# php file is not open with nginx-macOs

Tags: macos, nginx, nginx-config

I have some issue with nginx configuration in macos can anyone help me

Here is my `nginx.conf`

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root /Users/jurde/www/;
            index index.html index.htm index.php;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
            root           html;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}
    }


    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}


    # HTTPS server
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       443 ssl;
    #    server_name  localhost;

    #    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
    #    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

    #    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    #    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    #    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}
    include servers/*;
}
```

If i open `127.0.0.1/index.php` then it showing error

[Here is error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4Thm.png)

**Error Log**

```
2019/06/12 21:39:12 [error] 4237#0: *3 kevent() reported that connect() failed (61: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "127.0.0.1"
```

if i open `127.0.0.1/index.html` then it's working fine

PHP version is 7.1 and it is working fine

i'm using [Laravel](https://laravel.com/) project is working fine. but core php project is not open

please help me any help will appreciate

Comment: Does the error log indicate the cause of the error?

Comment: i add the error log. can you please check once

Comment: Interestingly, the `server` block shown in your question, serves `index.html` from `/Users/jurde/www/index.html` but `index.php` from `html/index.php` (relative to the default Nginx directory). Is that what you intended?

Comment: `/Users/jurde/www/index.html` this is working but `/Users/jurde/www/index.php` is not working. path is currect might be issuw with nginx conf file

Comment: You should probably move the `root` statement into the `server` block so that both the `location / { ... }` block and the `location ~ \.php$ { ... }` block inherit the same value.

Comment: still not working